# sendmail attachment is empty

Tags: centos, sendmail, troubleshooting

I am trying to include an attachment to my sendmail eml file.
The current eml file (order.eml) has the following contents

```
From: Sender <sender@email.com>
To: client@email.co.za
Subject: Report
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="B835649000072104Jul07"

--B835649000072104Jul07
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="US-ASCII"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: inline

Body Copy

--B835649000072104Jul07
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="por5151.pdf"
base64 por5151.pdf

--B835649000072104Jul07--
```

both the order.eml and por5151.pdf file are in the same directory and I try to send it with

```
# /usr/sbin/sendmail -t < order.eml
```

When the email arrives I can see the por5151.pdf in the attachments but it is blank (0 bytes). I don't know why this is and I am struggling to fix it

Comment: Are those the actual contents?  Because that attachment is 0 bytes. ;-) The eml-file must contain the data – according to the headers, a base64-encoded pdf-file – it won't parse the headers to find, encode, and include the contents itself.

Comment: Do you know how I would be able to do that? I've never added attachments before so I'm very noob at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would need to do is include the file below the

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="por5151.pdf"
```

line while you generate the `.eml` file. You can do so using the `base64` utility:

```
base64 por5151.pdf
```

Make sure the closing boundary (`--B835649000072104Jul07--`) gets inserted behind that.

`sendmail` doesn't interpret the file that you hand it, and therefore doesn't magically insert the contents of the `.pdf` file.

Comment: Hi Anthon, I made an edit to the question adding the base64 poer5151.pdf but the file seems to still be empty, did I add in the base64 correctly?

Comment: @trent No you need to put the **output of that command** into .eml file while you generate it. I never assumed you would be editing this file by hand.

Comment: Ooooooooh! I'm an idiot, I thought base64 was eml syntax I didn't realise it was a shell command! That worked perfectly thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

I have created below script to attach a CSV File. Its truncating the column name of CSV incorrectly and also there is one more file gets  with email, namely 'ATT0001.txt'.

```
(
echo "From:"$1;
echo "To:"$2;
echo "Subject:"$3;
echo "MIME-Version: 1.0";
echo "Content-Type:multipart/mixed; boundary=\"B835649000072104Jul07\"";

echo "--B835649000072104Jul07";
echo "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"";
echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit";
echo "Content-Disposition: inline";
echo "";
echo "$4";

echo "--B835649000072104Jul07";
echo "Content-Type: text/csv";
echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64";
echo "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$5\"";
base64 "$5"

echo "--B835649000072104Jul07";
) | sendmail -t
```